# Bedeutung von "zu lösen gehen"

Tags: meaning

> Oberbürgermeister Jens Peter bedankte sich für die Anregung und versprach, zu prüfen, ob das technisch **zu lösen geht.**

*Aus der Sächsischen Zeitung*

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck "gehen zu + Inf", falls es solchen überhaupt gibt und kann man es auch bei anderen Verben verwenden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*»gehen + zu«* bedeutet so viel wie *»möglich sein«*.

> prüfen, ob das technisch zu lösen geht

bedeutet also so viel wie:

> prüfen, ob es möglich ist, das technisch zu lösen

¹Die Verbindung *»gehen + Infinitiv mit ›zu‹«* wird als umgangssprachlich klassifiziert, diese dagegen als standardsprachlich:

> - sein + Infinitiv mit »zu«
> - bleiben + Infinitiv mit »zu«
> - stehen + Infinitiv mit »zu«
> - geben + Infinitiv mit »zu«

Beispiele:

> - Das Bild geht nicht zu befestigen. (Für standardsprachlich: *Das Bild kann nicht befestigt werden.*)
> - Der Schmerz ist kaum zu ertragen. (Für: *Der Schmerz kann kaum ertragen werden.*)
> - Das Ergebnis bleibt abzuwarten. (Für: *Das Ergebnis muss abgewartet werden.*)
> - Das steht zu erwarten. (Für: *Das wird erwartet.*)
> - Es gibt viel zu tun. (Für: *Vieles muss getan werden.*)

<sub>¹Quelle ab Verweisstelle: DUDEN Richtiges und gutes Deutsch</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Besser wäre folgende gleichbedeutende Formulierung gewesen:

> [Er] versprach, zu prüfen, ob das technisch **gelöst werden kann.**

Das Ausdruck »etwas geht« kann als Synonym für »etwas funktioniert« verwendet werden:

> Ich habe deine Kaffeemaschine repariert, jetzt **geht** sie wieder.
>   Ich habe deine Kaffeemaschine repariert, jetzt **funktioniert** sie wieder.

Comment: Vielleicht ergänzen "ob es technisch lösbar *ist*" und "ob es technisch geht" oder "technisch zu lösen ist".

Answer (score 2):

In diesem Kontext wird es ganz klar als Synonym zu „lassen“ gebraucht. Der Satz bedeutet also so viel wie:

> Oberbürgermeister Jens Peter [...] versprach, zu prüfen, ob sich das technisch lösen lässt.

Es handelt sich dabei aber (meiner Meinung nach) nicht um einen standardsprachlichen Ausdruck, wie er in einer Zeitung stehen sollte.

„Gehen“ kann aber standardsprachlich verwendet werden, um allgemein auszudrücken, dass etwas möglich ist, sich etwas machen lässt¹, dann allerdings ohne Infinitivgruppe. Z. B.:

> – Lässt sich feststellen, wer das Paket angenommen hat?
>
> – Klar, das geht.

---

¹ http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen#Bedeutung10a